# group every 3 count rows with mysql query

Tags: mysql

can anyone help me to group every 3 counts rows???
I have data like this

| num | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

and i want result like this

| num | count(num) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

Comment: Does it mean each row in the 3-rows group has the same content?

Comment: Your example has no edge-cases. What would this data output:

`(num:score)
    1:3,
    1:3,
    2:3,
    2:3,
    1:3,
    3:3,
    4:3,
    4:3,
    4:3,
    5:3,
    4:2,
    6:3,
    6:1,
    6:2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to group every 3 rows. But without giving supplementary conditions, we can only take assumptions on how you would like to group. Supposing each row in the 3-rows group has the same content and the score value from the base table has no influence on grouping, I guess you just want to get the num once for every 3 rows as the 3 rows have the same num. Besides, we use a constant value `3` for `count(num)` column.  If all my assumptions come true, try this:

```
select num, 3 as 'count(num)' 
from (select num,@row_id:=@row_id+1 as row_id 
     from test,(select @row_id:=0) t1 ) t2
where row_id mod 3 =0
order by num
;
```